# Does my character know he's ill while incubating a disease?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, metagaming, disease

My character was bitten by a Dire Rat and through accidental meta-gaming reasons, I know he's incubating Filth Fever. I want to ask the Paladin in our party to remove it before it can affect my stats, however, I don't really know if my character would know he's ill before the stat damage occurs. Is there any ruling for this?

Comment: @ChumpNicholson Yes, that works in fluff, however I'd like to know if there is a ruling for that anyway.

Comment: @Feathercrown: This question is about 3.5e, not 5e. (Also, [don't answer in comments](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6533/33569).)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> ***Disease***
>
> When a character is injured by a contaminated attack, touches an item
> smeared with diseased matter, or consumes disease-tainted food or
> drink, he must make an immediate Fortitude saving throw. If he
> succeeds, the disease has no effect—his immune system fought off the
> infection. If he fails, he takes damage after an incubation period.
> Once per day afterward, he must make a successful Fortitude saving
> throw to avoid repeated damage. Two successful saving throws in a row
> indicate that he has fought off the disease and recovers, taking no
> more damage.
>
> **These Fortitude saving throws can be rolled secretly so that the**
> **player doesn’t know whether the disease has taken hold.**

Emphasis mine, that last line only makes sense if the character doesn't know.

But, of course, even if the character doesn't know that he's incubating a disease for sure, he could suspect it. *Dire Rats* are animals, if the character (or any member of the party that witnessed the attack) has ranks in the skill **Knowledge (Nature)**, he could know that these creatures have an infectious bite, and that you *could* have been affected, and suggest healing magic just as a preventive measure.

Comment: You could guess there is a chance you have caught something but remove disease must surpass a DC check against the infection. The DM could note the success/failure of the roll but not tell you whether it was removed. Could work well for character development, is the disease really gone? Perhaps that is hanging over the character, they wake one morning after sleeping outside - is that ache in your joints just from camping and the damp air or is the infection slowly creeping up on you?

Comment: @LioElbammalf [Remove Disease](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/removeDisease.htm) doesn't have to surpass any check, you may have mistook it with the [pathfinder version](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/remove-disease/).

Comment: you're right, I did get them mixed up, thanks for picking up on that. Would have been a good idea otherwise! :)